# How to add a linkedin link to jekyll pages on github?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I tried to insert the linkedin link in the _config.yml but its throwing an error that the page cant be found.

Comment: The exact code for config and error message is needed if you want an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

go to your linked in profile then copy the address that is below your profile picture starting after https://ke.linkedin.com/in/

Then go to go to your _config.yml in your blog file in github, then paste the code you copied earlier to `linkedin` in `footer_links` section. Remember to space after the colon,like so 
`linkedin_username: user-name-256ra147`   and thats it, you are now linkedin! Hope it helps.

Comment: According to the social.html file in my stock minima-themed Jekyll Pages installation, it's "linkedin_username", not "linkedin"; and it's in the _config.yml file.

Comment: As of 2020, this has been updated to be under the `social_links` section of `_config.yml`, and is specified using `linkedin: USERNAME`. See [the latest jekyll/minima specification](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_config.yml).

Comment: While the change mentioned by @prrao is the current state in the master branch, that still has not been released yet. For the current latest released version 2.5.1 of the theme `linkedin_username` is still the [correct approach](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/38a84a949f9753c4542e25f422935f59b4913053/_includes/social.html#L7)!

Answer (score 1):

Still with Minima 2.5.1 (even with remote theme), so have to add as

```
linkedin_username: user-name
```

But I don't like the default vertical listing of the social links, and prefer the horizontal listing.  So I customized the footer.html as follows:

```
<footer class="site-footer h-card">
  <data class="u-url" href="{{ "/" | relative_url }}"></data>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    {%- if site.github_username -%}
    <ul class="contact-list">
      <a href="https://github.com/{{ site.github_username| cgi_escape | escape }}"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="{{ '/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#github' | relative_url }}"></use></svg> <span class="username">{{ site.github_username| escape }}</span></a>
      &emsp;
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/{{ site.linkedin_username| cgi_escape | escape }}"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="{{ '/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#linkedin' | relative_url }}"></use></svg> <span class="username">{{ site.linkedin_username| escape }}</span></a>
      &emsp;
      <a href="https://twitter.com/{{ site.twitter_username| cgi_escape | escape }}"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="{{ '/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#twitter' | relative_url }}"></use></svg> <span class="username">{{ site.twitter_username| escape }}</span></a>
    </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
  
</footer>
```